# Why awk '{ print }' doesn't start a new line but loops on space char

Tags: shell, awk

I have this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

LINES=$(awk '{ print }' filename.txt) 
for LINE in $LINES; do
  echo "$LINE"
done
```

And filename.txt has this content

```
Loreum ipsum dolores 
Loreum perche non se imortale
```

The shell script is iterating all spaces of the lines in filename.txt while it is supposed to loop only those two lines.

But when I type the "awk '{ print }' filename.txt" in terminal then it loops ok.
Any explanations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your AWK script must be simplified from what you're actually using because this is equivalent to what you posted: `LINES=$(<filename.txt)` (with the same problem).

Answer (score 3):

The `$(...)` construct absorbs *all* the output from awk as one large string, and then `for LINE in $LINES` splits on whitespace.  You want this construct instead:

```
#! /bin/sh

while read LINE; do
    printf '%s\n' "$LINE"
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: I tried this version, but the last line in filename.txt is not printed. Any suggestions why?

Comment: @user: The file may not end in a newline. By the way +1 for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, another thing you can do is temporarily change your IFS (Internal Field Separator) variable.  If you update your shell script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="
"
LINES=$(awk '{ print }' filename.txt) 
for LINE in $LINES; do
  echo "$LINE"
done
```

This updates the IFS to be a newline instead of ' ' which should also do what you want.

Just another suggestion.

Comment: If by 'many' you mean 'bash'... it's not part of POSIX.1-2008, and personally I don't even rely on the stuff in the -2001 shell spec unless I have other good reasons to think it's universal.  Poke at OpenSolaris's `/bin/sh` sometime (*not* `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`).

Comment: Old beard grumbles aside, `$(awk '{print}' filename.txt)` here gains you *nothing* over `$(cat filename.txt)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `LINES` as an array as all lines are stored as an array there.

Here's an example how to loop over the lines:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html#SCRIPTARRAY

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: my point is that if there was an array it would be possible to loop through it with a `for` as that would be pretty close to what the OP has presented. The link points to an example how such thing can be achieved.